# C++ map char input variable through BasePairMap to get output integer variable

Tags: c++

I am a Python and SAS developer getting a bit lost with C++. All I am trying to do is take a `char` value, `c` as defined below:

```
std::string s1 = argv[1];

for (char c : s1)
```

...and map it to the below base pair map as so:

```
typedef std::map<string, int> BasePairMap;
BasePairMap m;

m["0"] = 48;
m["1"] = 49;
m["2"] = 50;
m["3"] = 51;
m["4"] = 52;
m["5"] = 53;
m["6"] = 54;
m["7"] = 55;
m["8"] = 56;
m["9"] = 57;

int in_arg = m[c];
```

This produces the build errors:

> Error (active)    E0349   no operator "[]" matches these
>   operands  SkyQChannelChanger  g:\Visual Studio 2017\C++
>   Projects\SkyQChannelChanger\SkyQChannelChanger\Main.cpp   144
>   operand types are: BasePairMap [ char ]

...and:

> Error C2679   binary '[': no operator found which takes a right-hand
>   operand of type 'char' (or there is no acceptable
>   conversion)   SkyQChannelChanger  g:\visual studio 2017\c++
>   projects\skyqchannelchanger\skyqchannelchanger\main.cpp   144

I'm getting pretty annoyed with myself for not being able to figure out what seemingly is a fairly simple task.

The super high level purpose of this exercise is:

- Feed my `basepairmap` the character `"4"` for example via the variable `c`.
- Create an integer variable called `in_arg` that would be assigned the value of `52`.

...can anyone please `/explainitlikeimfive` for me?

Thanks

Comment: `m[c]` … `c` is not a `string`, so cannot be used to lookup into the map. You can do `m[std::string(1,c)]`, which is a bit ugly, but would work.

Comment: Double quotes create character arrays (`"string"`, commonly referred to as strings), single quotes create character constants (`'c'`).

Comment: Is your map just an example, or are you trying to convert a digit into its value? If that, you can just use `int in_arg = c - '0';`, without a map.

Comment: @ChrisMM - I can live with ugly. Your solution worked, thank you very much for that. I have becoming less ugly and more beautiful at C++ on the agenda this year, but it's a level of complexity higher than Python and at present I have no call to use it for anything paid, so it will progress at hobby speed only...

Comment: @VladFeinstein Hi, Vlad. Thanks for the input. A map is required though as there a series of command line arguments this script receives, that get mapped to c, through the basepairmap and out the other side as in_arg.